# table not reversing using the [].reverse.call function (with external html file)

Tags: jquery, html

I got trouble getting the following code to work:

```
[].reverse.call($("#myTable > tbody > tr")).appendTo("#myTable > tbody");
```

It works when I use it normally.

I have an external html file which is created by a Java program.

This files has html table code within it, starting from <tr>.

I will post the code below:

Main HTML file:

```
 <div id="title">
    Title
 </div>

 <div id="data">
    <table>
        <tbody>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#data table tbody').load('data.html');
         [].reverse.call($("#data tbody tr")).appendTo("#data tbody");
});
```

And finally my data.html external script (it is all in one line as the program creates it like this):

```
 <tr><td>some text1</td><td>some text1</td></tr><tr><td>some
 text2</td><td>some text2</td></tr>
```

Sorry, don't know how to explain it better, hopefully it is understandable.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [callback on the `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function). Currently, you're trying to do the reverse in what amounts to the same millisecond you're asking jQuery to retrieve data.html. By using a callback, you're telling jQuery to "Load this and once that's completed, do this other thing".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#data table tbody').load('data.html', function(){ 
         [].reverse.call($("#data tbody tr")).appendTo("#data tbody");
    });
});
```